# VS Code. Параметры class id в HTML

Tags: visual-studio-code

Перешел на *VS Code*.

Как настроить в *VS Code* автокомплит параметров в HTML так же, как это делает *Sublime Text*?
Т.е., чтобы начиная набирать "cl" в `<div cl></div>` редактор предлагал выбрать параметр `class`, при выборе - вписывал его, открывал и закрывал кавычки.

Comment: Проверил. У меня это работает по умолчанию для файлов c расширением .html

Answer (score 0):

VS Code расчитана на то что каждый ее будет настраивать по своим надобнастям.

Например для работы с HTML5 с автозакрытием тегов, подсветкой и небольшой справкой рекомендую установить следующее расширение:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=abusaidm.html-snippets

Также это расширение для удобного автопоиска css классов в workspace:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion